# Host sidekiq container along side rails puma container in docker swarm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-swarm, sidekiq

I have a docker swarm cluster that hosts my rails app and sidekiq as separate containers.

The API application writes an incoming uploaded file into the public folder and sends the path to sidekiq worker to upload to s3. I used docker volume mapping for this.

Because of this dependency, I need a sidekiq container running in all the nodes where my API application is running.

Is there any way to tell swarm to deploy a sidekiq container, when it is deploying an API container in a new node?

Or, is there any workaround which can solve my problem without volume mapping dependency in the first place?

My docker-stack.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    image: rails_app
    command: bundle exec rails s -e production
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - app-assets:/app/public/assets
    networks:
      - my-network
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==worker"
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
  worker:
    image: rails_app
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -e production
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - app-assets:/app/public/assets
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==worker"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s

networks:
  my-network:

volumes:
  app-assets:
```

Answer (score 1):

Even after 3 days of googling, I was not able to find any such configurations with the Docker swarm. but I was able to solve this bottleneck by using NFS for volume mapping.

More info on the NFS : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04